# I don't have a gpg.conf file

Tags: gnupg

I'm following [Riseup's guide](https://riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices#selecting-a-keyserver-and-configuring-your-machine-to-refresh-your-keyring) to selecting a keyserver and configuring my machine to refresh my keyring, but there's no `gpg.conf` file in `~/.gnupg`. Apparently my (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) system is supposed to come with a `gpg.conf` file at `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`. Any idea as to why I don't have one? How can I get one? Thanks.

Comment: You have to make a *gpg.conf* file. Read [here](https://keys.openpgp.org/about/usage) under **Gnupg** to locate and refresh keys..

Comment: @PaulBenson where? I don't have a `dirmngr.conf` file either.

Comment: What do you mean? Where - what?

Comment: Some research revealed this answer on unix.stackexchange.com: [Generating default gpg.conf with default gnupg2 utils](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654829/generating-default-gpg-conf-with-default-gnupg2-utils)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this command to list all the directories that gpg is looking into:

```
$ gpgconf --list-dirs
```

I'm not using ubuntu myself by I would guess you could find it at `/etc/gnupg/gpgconf.conf`.